# Парсер текста между тегами

Tags: c#, html, парсер

Необходимо на C# сделать парсер погоды, температуры воздуха. Нашел `HtmlAgilityPack`, но никак не могу въехать как пользоваться. Мне нужна инфа между тегами

```
<td class"bla ble">31</td>
```

Помогите въехать или подскажите где посмотреть примеры, в `google` их много, но все какие то закрученные.

В возможном дубликате речь идет о парсинге атрибутов.

Comment: Поглядите примеры [тут](http://html-agility-pack.net/), [туториалы тут](http://html-agility-pack.net/api)

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [AngleSharp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668285/213987)

Comment: Блин, у нас же есть [эталонный ответ на парсинг html в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/213987), а я всё мучаюсь подбираю каждый примеры для очередного ответа. Вопрос -- на закрытие.

Comment: @AK ваш вариант ответа, лично для меня, более понятен, чем в ответах заданного ранее, ссылку которого вы указали. Я сделал при помощи HtmlAgilityPack, но мне понравился Ваш пример, он выглядит более проще, подскажите, не могу найти, как правильно подключить к проекту  AngleSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp).

Ваш пример будет примерно такого вида:

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
    var document = parser.Parse(@"<body>
<div class='product'>
    <a href='/url1.html'><img src='img1.jpg' alt=''></a>
    Hello, world
    <div class='comments-likes'>1</div>
    <table id='menutable'>
        <tr>
            <td>Head1</td>
            <td>Head2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='bla ble'>31</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='bla ble'>32</td>
            <td>content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
    <a href='http://www.ya.ru/q=asdf'>
</div>
</body>");

var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll("table#menutable td.bla.ble");
foreach (var cell in cells)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cell.Text());
}
```

Наиболее просто подключить AngleSharp при помощи механизма NuGet пакетов, встроенного в студию.

В окне Solution Explorer щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на нужном проекте и выберите пункт Manage NuGet Packages. Затем выполните поиск пакета AngleSharp (требуется подключение к интернету) и установите.

Механизм NuGet очень удобен, я рекомендую потратить некоторое время на его изучение.

Comment: Как он подключается? Это не .dll? Спасибо.

Comment: @Winteriscoming Я подключаю его при помощи NuGet. Дополнил ответ кратким описанием того, как поставить, плюс в сети легко найдёте множество статей.

Comment: Не так `Console.WriteLine(cell.Text());` а так `Console.WriteLine(cell.TextContent);`. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример выборки значений из элементов `<td></td>` структуру HTML документа для парсинга взял [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/html/TABLE).

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(@"C:\myHtml.html");
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
               .Descendants("table")
               .SelectMany(y => y.SelectNodes("//tr/td"))
               .Select(s => s.InnerText)
               .ToList();
```